# Docslist Quota: How do I avoid it on migration?

Tags: google-apps-script, quota

I am creating a folder tree of 1700 folders for my uploaded documents and have hit a Docslist quota limit. Waiting a day or so is fine in this case but for migrating future customers to Google Apps, I would like a better approach than 
   var newfolder = DocsList.getFolderById(parent).createFolder(name); until fail

Comment: I think my best approach is to create the folder structure on my local machine and upload that (the documents themselves were in a database not inside folders)

Comment: I've created an issue for you to star and follow. This is something I care about as well. http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1944

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, the answer was definitely to establish the folder structure outside apps and upload it via chrome. It took seconds to add my empty folder tree compared with many minutes to add 200 folders in Apps Script.

Answer (score 2):

The power of google in my opinion is search. So maybe your first question should be do I need this much folders.

Solutions:
Use multiple admin accounts for big migrations.

And make use of your API's to migrate data

Comment: Thanks, while I agree that the folder structure may be redundant, my client does not

Comment: Then use multiple admin accounts.